How Can I Improve My Question on MathOverflow
I recently posted a question on MathOverflow, but it received downvotes. I'm not sure what specifically might have caused the downvotes, and I want to improve it to align better with the community's expectations.
Here is the link to my question: Symmetry of Zeros of the Completed $L$-function $\xi_L(s)$ .
Could someone help me understand what might be missing or unclear? I’d appreciate any advice on how to improve the question and avoid downvotes in the future. Thank you!

Maybe it was considered not to be at research level. You got an answer, which you accepted – isn't that more important than a couple of downvotes?

I agree.  Ignore a few downvotes.

This answers echoes the "ignore the few downvotes" comments of Gerry Myerson and Gerald Edgar, and adds one more remark.
Downvotes are not directly related to the quality of the question, or at least not always. I've seen some reviews where the related question seem to have been downvoted basing on the presence of precise keywords: for example "Riemann hypothesis" seem to trigger the suspect of some reviewers. Nevertheless not all depends on the presence of some keywords: this apparently elementary theoretical mechanics question and its accepted answer received one downvote without containing any particularly "sensitive" keyword. Definitely anything seem to depend on the accuracy of the reviewer (should I add "as it is customary for all things"?).

Did you really mean "sensible"?

@MoisheKohan thanks for pointing it out: I meant "sensitive", but the 'false friend' "sensible" fooled me. I've corrected the post.

I agree that it's a good guess that the phrase "verifying the generalized Riemann hypothesis" triggered some downvotes from people who didn't necessarily understand the question. I've been on this site since nearly the beginning and i continue to be baffled by some downvotes and votes to close (the only explanation I have is that the naysayers are not reading or thinking carefully). In particular, Fatima Majeed's question looks perfectly fine to me.
